# Quickly evaluating this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, intuition

I'm reviewing for the Math GRE Subject test and came across this question in the excellent [UCLA notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~chparkin/gre/Week1_solns.pdf).

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right).$$

If one attacks this with naive applications of L'Hospital after combining fractions, it quickly gets out of hand.
The suggested solution involves factoring it as

$$\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{\sin^2 x - x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x} = \left(\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\right)\left(\frac{\sin x + x}{x}\right)\left(\frac{\sin x - x}{x^{3}}\right),$$

where indeed each factor has a real positive limit.
I am wondering: **What intuition or thought process might lead me to this particular factorization?** Such a factorization seems non-obvious to me as it requires the introduction of another factor of $x^2$ into the numerator.

---

Edit: Thanks to everyone's clear responses, I now understand:

1. Taylor expansions of trig functions are immensely powerful in evaluating limits, in this case turning the problem into a limit of a rational function.
2. If a factor of a limit exists and is nonzero, it can be factored out without affecting convergence of the product. Formally, suppose $\lim f(x)$ exists and $g(x)$ is a factor of $f(x)$.
   Then if $\lim g(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ exists also. That is to say, one can be "opportunistic" about simplifying ones limits if a factor with a real nonzero limit is discovered.

Comment: As soon as you see $x^2-y^2$ don't you automatically do $(x+y)(x-y)$ ?

Comment: Some other posts about the same limit (found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csin%5E2%20x%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1)): 

[Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2910595), 

[Find the limit without use of L'Hôpital or Taylor series: $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/400541) and ...

Comment: ...and [Trigonometric Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\tan^2x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/584563). Some useful tips on searching can be found here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks for the tip about Approach0--I wasn't aware of that site. And in general, thank you to all for your insight and guidance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots,$$you know that$$\sin(x)+x=2x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$and that$$\sin(x)-x=-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots.$$Therefore both limits$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)+x}x\text{ and }\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}$$exist; they are equal to $2$ and to $-\frac16$ respectively. This explains why that decomposition is used.

Answer (score 5):

OK, let's talk through the thought process.

- When I see a difference of two fractions, I give them common
  denominators first, as per your second $=$.
- I can't help but factorise the new numerator's difference of two
  squares after that.
- Since there's a division by $\sin^2 x$, which $\to0$ as $x\to0$, I
  need to take out a $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{-2}$ factor before
  I can go any further.
- That leaves me with $\frac{(\sin x+x)(\sin x-x)}{x^4}$. There are any
  number of ways I could write that as a product of two other factors,
  but I don't want to factor out a limit outside $\Bbb
     R\setminus\{0\}$, in case I get an indeterminate form. (That same
  concern motivation the previous handling of $\sin^{-2}x$.) Well,
  $\frac{\sin x}{x}\sim1\implies\frac{\sin x+x}{x}\sim2$, so finally
  the sought limit is twice $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$.

Comment: Nice detailed expression of what I just gave a cursory overview of.

Answer (score 4):

Once you know that
$\dfrac{\sin x}{x}
\to 1$,
and similar,
fairly simple limits,
it becomes natural
to try to make them appear
by extracting them
from more complicated expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has explicitly mentioned it, I am going to state for the record that the best way to evaluate limits in general is **not** actually via purely algebraic manipulation of the kind you are looking for, but rather via asymptotic expansions (which is how all computer algebra systems do it):
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

As $x → 0$:

$\sin(x) ∈ x - \lfrac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)$.

Thus $\lfrac1{x^2} - \lfrac1{\sin(x)^2} ∈ \lfrac1{x^2} - \lfrac1{(x - \lfrac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5))^2} = \lfrac1{x^2} - \lfrac1{x^2·(1 - \lfrac{x^2}{3} + O(x^4))}$

$ ⊆ \lfrac1{x^2} - \lfrac{1+\lfrac{x^2}{3}+O(x^4)}{x^2} ⊆ -\lfrac13 + O(x^2)$

Now you may ask, how did I know how much of the expansion of $\sin$ I would need? Well, I did not have to know. If you expand too little, you will obtain too loose asymptotic bounds at the end, and you can trace to see which expansions you need a tighter bound on. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2504179/21820) for more detailed explanation and examples.

Furthermore, we can sometimes utilize asymptotic expansion to find a purely algebraic proof, such as for this limit. Specifically, if $f(x) \gg g(x)$, then $\lfrac1{f(x)} - \lfrac1{f(x)+g(x)}$ $= \lfrac{g(x)}{f(x)·(f(x)+g(x))}$ $\sim \lfrac{g(x)}{f(x)^2}$, where $A \sim B$ denotes that $A-B \ll A,B$ (i.e. the discrepancy is negligible compared to the terms themselves). As a difference, the most significant terms may cancel, but once combined we will no longer have such cancellation. That is why we have to combine in this case:

$\lfrac1{x^2} - \lfrac1{\sin(x)^2} = \lfrac{\sin(x)^2-x^2}{x^2·\sin(x)^2}$.

And by the same asymptotic reasoning the next step is also well-motivated by the fact that as $x → 0$, we have $\sin(x)^2 \in x^2·(1+o(1))$, equivalently $\sin(x)^2/x^2 ≈ 1$ and often denoted as $\sin(x)^2 \sim x^2$. So we can without thinking do:

$\lfrac{\sin(x)^2-x^2}{x^2·\sin(x)^2} = \lfrac{x^2}{\sin(x)^2} · \lfrac{\sin(x)^2-x^2}{x^4}$

Even if we do not see the factorization, we can proceed systematically in the same fashion of factoring out significant terms:

$\lfrac{\sin(x)^2-x^2}{x^4} = \lfrac{x^2·(1+(\sin(x)-x)/x)^2-x^2}{x^4}$

And from there everything is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to recreate the steps.

Step 1): We are subtracting two fractions so let's have a common denominator, leading to
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\sin^2x  - x^2 \over x^2\sin^2 x}$$

Step 2): I see a difference of two squares so let's factor:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{(\sin x - x)(\sin x + x) \over x^2 \sin^2 x}$$
Step 3): I know the limit of ${\sin x \over x}$ is $1$, so I'll stick an $x^2$ in the numerator to place over the $\sin^2 x$. The result is
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{x^2 \over \sin^2 x}{(\sin x - x)(\sin x + x) \over x^4}$$
Step 4): I know that $\sin x - x$ is $O(x^3)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, and $\sin x + x$ is $O(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. This suggests writing the limit as
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{x^2 \over \sin^2 x}{(\sin x - x) \over x^3}{(\sin x + x) \over x}$$ 
And there we have it.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac {1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2x} = \left(\frac {1}{x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)\left(\frac {1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right) = \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac {x}{x}+\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)\left(\frac {x}{x}-\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)
$$

so

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac {1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right) =2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sin x}\right) = 2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right) = 2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right) = 2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+o(x^4)-1\right) = -\frac 13
$$